# how pass parameter from one controller to another controller and use tis parameter in second controller, Many to many relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

i have  2 tables (**Camp**,**speselaization**) , because m-m relation ,there middle table (detail_camps_camps_specialization),i want when i create new camp i want pass parameter ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MboCX.png)**camp.id**),then i need create information in middle table for this current camp,how do that[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7kfW.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl2ch.png)

i try pass parameter of (camp.id) when ended in create and call of creator of(**detail_camps_camps_specialization**)

Answer (score 0):

You must Change  routevaluesLike Like the code below

```
return RedirectToAction("Create", "detail_camps_camps_specialization",
                                  new { Campid = camp.camp_id });
```

also You can Use TempData

```
TempData["Campid"] = camp.camp_id;


var TempData_ = TempData["Campid"];
```